# Test Execution is getting failed

Tags: apex

I am trying to run a test class. but it is getting failed. For all classes it is getting failed.
even though I have cleared the test history.

for the particular which i am trying to execute run test.
it is showing following error

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Here is my code.

```
@istest(seealldata=false)
Global class McKessonNewIncidentCreation_Test 
{
    static Testmethod void inboundemailtest1()
    {
       Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();
       Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();

        //insert account
        Account acct = new Account();
        acct.Name = 'Wellspan - Good Samaritan ';
        insert acct;

         Account acct1 = new Account();
        acct1.Name = 'McKesson';
        insert acct1;
        // inserting user
        Profile p = [select id,name from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator'];
        User testUser = new User();
        testUser.LastName = 'Test User';
        testUser.FirstName = 'test1';
        testUser.Email = 'ishelpdesk@wellspan.org';
        testUser.UserName = 'testuserxbhg@dellservice.com';
        testUser.profileId = p.id;
        testUser.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
        testUser.Alias = 'alias';
        testUser.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
        testUser.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
        testUser.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
        testUser.BMCServiceDesk__Account_Name__c = 'Wellspan - Good Samaritan';
        testUser.BMCServiceDesk__Account_ID__c = acct.id;
        insert testUser;

        BMCServiceDesk__Status__c status = new BMCServiceDesk__Status__c();
        status.Name = 'OPENED';
        status.BMCServiceDesk__inactive__c = false;
        status.BMCServiceDesk__appliesToIncident__c = true;
        insert status;

        BMCServiceDesk__Status__c status1 = new BMCServiceDesk__Status__c();
        status1.Name = 'REJECTED';
        insert status1;

        BMCServiceDesk__Status__c status2 = new BMCServiceDesk__Status__c();
        status2.Name = 'RESOLVED';
        insert status2;

        BMCServiceDesk__Status__c status3 = new BMCServiceDesk__Status__c();
        status3.Name = 'CLOSED';
        insert status3;

        BMCServiceDesk__Action__c action = new BMCServiceDesk__Action__c();
        action.Name = 'Email Received';
        insert action;

        Email_Service_Address__c es = new Email_Service_Address__c();
        es.name='RF-Mckesson';
        es.EmailServiceAddress__c='rf-mckesson@2v14mdnjx10p9xwbwin641qn3ikoez8kcfjtvgi63hth210byo.e-1o1xeeas.cs15.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com';
        insert es;

         email.subject = 'McKesson HealthTicket Incident #[999999999]';
        email.plainTextBody  = 'Test body';
        email.fromAddress = 'ishelpdesk@wellspan.org';
        List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
        toAddress.add('rf-mckesson@2v14mdnjx10p9xwbwin641qn3ikoez8kcfjtvgi63hth210byo.e-1o1xeeas.cs15.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com');
        email.htmlBody = 'Test Html';
        email.toAddresses = toAddress;
        Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] binaryAttachments = new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[1];  
        Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment binaryAttachment = new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment();
        binaryAttachment.Filename = 'test.txt';
        String algorithmName = 'HMacSHA1';
        Blob b = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf('test'),
        Blob.valueOf('test_key'));
        binaryAttachment.Body = b;
        binaryAttachments[0] =  binaryAttachment ;
        email.binaryAttachments = binaryAttachments ;
        Messaging.InboundEmail.textAttachment attachment = new Messaging.InboundEmail.textAttachment();
        attachment.body = 'my attachment text';
        attachment.fileName = 'textfile.txt';
        attachment.mimeTypeSubType = 'text/plain';
        email.textAttachments = new Messaging.inboundEmail.textAttachment[] { attachment };
        McKessonNewIncidentCreation testInbound=new McKessonNewIncidentCreation ();
        testInbound.handleInboundEmail(email,env);
    }
    static testmethod void inboundemailtest2()
    {
        Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
        Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();

        BMCServiceDesk__Status__c status = new BMCServiceDesk__Status__c();
        status.Name = 'OPEN';
        insert status;

        BMCServiceDesk__Action__c action = new BMCServiceDesk__Action__c();
        action.Name = 'EmailRD';
        insert action;

        Email_Service_Address__c es = new Email_Service_Address__c();
        es.name='RF-Mckesson';
        es.EmailServiceAddress__c='rf-mckesson@2v14mdnjx10p9xwbwin641qn3ikoez8kcfjtvgi63hth210byo.e-1o1xeeas.cs15.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com';
        insert es;

        List<String> ccAddress = new List<String>();
       ccAddress.add('testmail@test.com');
       email.subject = '(Ref:IN:00000000)';
       email.fromAddress = 'exaddress@email.com';
       List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
        toAddress.add('rf-mckesson@2v14mdnjx10p9xwbwin641qn3ikoez8kcfjtvgi63hth210byo.e-1o1xeeas.cs15.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com');
        email.plainTextBody  = 'Testingbody';
        email.htmlBody = 'Test Html';
        email.toAddresses = toAddress;
        email.ccAddresses = ccAddress;
        McKessonNewIncidentCreation obj= new McKessonNewIncidentCreation();
        obj.handleInboundEmail(email, env);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to resolve the error in your test class which says `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`.

Comment: Please post your tested class code and your test.

Comment: Make sure you've created all your test data appropriately

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Thanks to all,somehow i fixed it, first i change seeall data to true, then modified insertion of action, just i change the instance name of action object.